# failure to converge after 300 iterations. Last change (0.1382513330677284) was greater than tolerance (0.001)

Tags: julia, mds

I'm using MDS in julia. 'Here is my code

```
D = pairwise(Euclidean(), mat_new)
M = fit(MetricMDS, D; distances=true, maxoutdim=2, metric=isotonic)
```

And I got error saying

```
failure to converge after 300 iterations. Last change (0.1382513330677284) was greater than tolerance (0.001)
```

But if I use the code below instead

```
D = pairwise(Euclidean(), mat_new)
M = fit(MetricMDS, D; distances=true, maxoutdim=2)
Yte = predict(M)
```

It works fine.

I went through the document saying that "isotonic: converts dissimilarity values to ordinal disparities to perform non-metric MDS"

Does the "metric = isotonic" matter here? Can I say the second block of code is performing non-metric MDS?

Comment: Can you better explain what would an answer to this question include?

Comment: @DanGetz I would like to perform a non-metric MDS. But when I followed the syntax"M = fit(MetricMDS, D; distances=true, maxoutdim=2, metric=isotonic)", there would be an error "failure to converge after 300 iterations. Last change (0.1382513330677284) was greater than tolerance (0.001)"

Comment: Can you give an example input which fails to converge. Since this definitely is input dependant (i.e. a specific `mat_new` which fails to converge)? Otherwise it is hard for readers to replicate error.